# Using custom mocks for components with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing a React-Native application in which I have a screen I need to test:

`MyScreen.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CustomTable from "./CustomTable";

export default MyScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return <CustomTable />;
  }
}
```

`CustomTable.ios.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import TableView from "react-native-tableview";

export default MyScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ...some stuff
        <TableView />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

`react-native-tableview` calls some iOS specific code so I have mocked it out by simply returning the android version (`CustomTable.android.js`) in the `__mocks__` folder

`__mocks__/CustomTable.ios.js`

```
import CustomAndroidTable from "../CustomTable.android";
export const CustomTable = CustomAndroidTable;
```

What I want to do is test `MyScreen.js` with Jest, but I want it to use the `__mock__/CustomTable.ios`. How do I go about getting it to do that? Is that even possible with Jest? My current test file looks like:

`tests/MyScreen.test.js`

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import MyScreen from "../src/MyScreen";

describe("test", () => {
  it("works", () => {
  jest.mock("../src/CustomTable.ios");
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <MyScreen />,
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But it still calls the original version of `CustomTable.ios`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call jest.mock outside of your suite test. It should be immediately after your imports.

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import MyScreen from "../src/MyScreen";

jest.mock("../src/CustomTable.ios");

describe("test", () => {
  it("works", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <MyScreen />,
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: I tried SO MANY solutions I found all over the place, but the crux for me was that the mock needs to be right below the imports, as you mentioned. Thanks!!